# Odoo 15 Internal Server Error on payment status page | Failed to render QWeb template : 'loop' - is it related to the sales confirmation template?

Tags: odoo, e-commerce, internal-server-error, odoo-15

I'm new to Odoo. We're running Odoo 15.0 for B2B and introducing B2C into the mix. Everything is working smoothly except for an error on the payment status page after payment completion. Payment is taken, but the Internal Server Error looks like this:

Failed to render QWeb template : 'loop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/15.0/odoo/addons/base/mc
yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
File "", line 115, in template
KeyError: 'loop'

Error when render the template
KeyError: 'loop'
Template:
Path: /div/div/t/div[1]/t/t[2]/table/tbody/tr
Node:

---

And then it cuts off on screen.

After payment is taken, the order is stuck in Sales Order status and doesn't convert to a completed sale in the system.

Any suggestions on what this could be?

We thought it could be an issue with orders requiring a signature confirmation and removed that option, but no matter what we try from a configuration standpoint, the error remains.